# Remove NaN Values From Right Column While Retaining Values In Left Columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have three dataframes that I merge together that I then remove the duplicates from. But when I remove duplicates from my last three columns, I get NaN values at the tops of the dataframe that I want to remove but can't seem to find a way of doing so.

Here is my code so far:

```
bDF=pd.read_csv(bRaw)
pDF=pd.read_csv(pRaw)
mDF=pd.read_csv(mRaw)
del bRaw,pRaw,mRaw

#Merge Together Datarames on the Value Role Name
dfs=[bDF,pDF,mDF]
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['R1'],
                                            how='outer'), dfs)
del bDF,pDF,mDF,dfs

#Rearrange Columns
cols=df_merged.columns.tolist()
cols=cols[0:1]+cols[-3:]+cols[1:5]
df_merged=df_merged[cols]
```

Output after merge:

```
+------+-----+------+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  R   |  C  |  D   | JC |   R    |   PM   |  Nme   |  Vle   |
+------+-----+------+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| JMAC | 305 | 3302 | I6 | Cofow  | Value1 | Value1 | Value1 |
| JMAC | 305 | 3915 | R6 | Cofow  | Value1 | Value1 | Value1 |
| JMAC | 301 | 3302 | I6 | Cofow  | Value1 | Value1 | Value1 |
| JMAC | 301 | 3915 | R6 | Cofow  | Value1 | Value1 | Value1 |
| JMAC | 305 | 3302 | I6 | Cofow  | Value2 | Value2 | Value2 |
| JMAC | 305 | 3915 | R6 | Cofow  | Value2 | Value2 | Value2 |
| JMAC | 301 | 3302 | I6 | Cofow  | Value2 | Value2 | Value2 |
| JMAC | 301 | 3915 | R6 | Cofow  | Value2 | Value2 | Value2 |
| JMAC | 305 | 3302 | I6 | Cofow  | Value3 | Value3 | Value3 |
| JMAC | 305 | 3915 | R6 | Cofow  | Value3 | Value3 | Value3 |
| JMAC | 301 | 3302 | I6 | Cofow  | Value3 | Value3 | Value3 |
| JMAC | 301 | 3915 | R6 | Cofow  | Value3 | Value3 | Value3 |
| JMAC | 305 | 3302 | I6 | Cofow  | Value4 | Value4 | Value4 |
| JMAC | 305 | 3915 | R6 | Cofow  | Value4 | Value4 | Value4 |
| JMAC | 301 | 3302 | I6 | Cofow  | Value4 | Value4 | Value4 |
| JMAC | 301 | 3915 | R6 | Cofow  | Value4 | Value4 | Value4 |
| JMAP | 301 | 3315 | I6 | Cofowd | Value6 | Value6 | Value6 |
| JMAP | 301 | 3916 | R6 | Cofowd | Value6 | Value6 | Value6 |
| JMAP | 305 | 3314 | I6 | Cofowd | Value6 | Value6 | Value6 |
| JMAP | 305 | 3315 | R6 | Cofowd | Value6 | Value6 | Value6 |
| JMAP | 305 | 3916 | R6 | Cofowd | Value6 | Value6 | Value6 |
| JMAP | 301 | 3315 | I6 | Cofowd | Value7 | Value7 | Value7 |
| JMAP | 301 | 3916 | R6 | Cofowd | Value7 | Value7 | Value7 |
| JMAP | 305 | 3314 | I6 | Cofowd | Value7 | Value7 | Value7 |
| JMAP | 305 | 3315 | R6 | Cofowd | Value7 | Value7 | Value7 |
| JMAP | 305 | 3916 | R6 | Cofowd | Value7 | Value7 | Value7 |
| JMAP | 301 | 3315 | I6 | Cofowd | Value8 | Value8 | Value8 |
| JMAP | 301 | 3916 | R6 | Cofowd | Value8 | Value8 | Value8 |
| JMAP | 305 | 3314 | I6 | Cofowd | Value8 | Value8 | Value8 |
| JMAP | 305 | 3315 | R6 | Cofowd | Value8 | Value8 | Value8 |
| JMAP | 305 | 3916 | R6 | Cofowd | Value8 | Value8 | Value8 |
| JMAP | 301 | 3315 | I6 | Cofowd | Value9 | Value9 | Value9 |
| JMAP | 301 | 3916 | R6 | Cofowd | Value9 | Value9 | Value9 |
| JMAP | 305 | 3314 | I6 | Cofowd | Value9 | Value9 | Value9 |
| JMAP | 305 | 3315 | R6 | Cofowd | Value9 | Value9 | Value9 |
| JMAP | 305 | 3916 | R6 | Cofowd | Value9 | Value9 | Value9 |
+------+-----+------+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I then go to remove duplicates from the first 4 columns, then the last three columns, finally the middle column:

```
#Remove Duplicate Values
df_merged[cols[0:-3]]=df_merged[cols[0:-3]].mask(df_merged[cols[:-3]].duplicated())
df_merged[cols[-3:]]=df_merged[cols[-3:]].mask(df_merged[cols[-3:]].duplicated())
df_merged[cols[4:5]]=df_merged[cols[4:5]].mask(df_merged[cols[4:5]].duplicated())
df_merged=df_merged.dropna(how='all')
```

My output is close to what the final form needs to be:

```
+------+-----+------+----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
|  R   |  C  |  D   | JC |   R   |   PM    |   Nme   |   Vle   |
+------+-----+------+----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| JMAC | 305 | 3302 | I6 | Cofow | Value1  | Value1  | Value1  |
| JMAC | 305 | 3915 | R6 |       | NaN     | NaN     | NaN     |
| JMAC | 301 | 3302 | I6 |       | NaN     | NaN     | NaN     |
| JMAC | 301 | 3915 | R6 |       | NaN     | NaN     | NaN     |
|      |     |      |    |       | Value2  | Value2  | Value2  |
|      |     |      |    |       | Value3  | Value3  | Value3  |
|      |     |      |    |       | Value4  | Value4  | Value4  |
|      |     |      |    |       | Value6  | Value6  | Value6  |
|      |     |      |    |       | Value7  | Value7  | Value7  |
| JMAP | 301 | 3315 | I6 | Cofow | Value8  | Value8  | Value8  |
| JMAP | 301 | 3916 | R6 |       | NaN     | NaN     | NaN     |
| JMAP | 305 | 3314 | I6 |       | NaN     | NaN     | NaN     |
| JMAP | 305 | 3315 | R6 |       | NaN     | NaN     | NaN     |
| JMAP | 305 | 3916 | R6 |       | NaN     | NaN     | NaN     |
|      |     |      |    |       | Value9  | Value9  | Value9  |
|      |     |      |    |       | Value10 | Value10 | Value10 |
|      |     |      |    |       | Value11 | Value11 | Value11 |
|      |     |      |    |       | Value12 | Value12 | Value12 |
|      |     |      |    |       | Value13 | Value13 | Value13 |
+------+-----+------+----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

My problem is that I want to get rid of my NaN values and shift the values up. So I want my end result to look something like:

```
+------+-----+------+----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
|  R   |  C  |  D   | JC |   R   |   PM    |   Nme   |   Vle   |
+------+-----+------+----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| JMAC | 305 | 3302 | I6 | Cofow | Value1  | Value1  | Value1  |
| JMAC | 305 | 3915 | R6 |       | Value2  | Value2  | Value2  |
| JMAC | 301 | 3302 | I6 |       | Value3  | Value3  | Value3  |
| JMAC | 301 | 3915 | R6 |       | Value4  | Value4  | Value4  |
|      |     |      |    |       | Value6  | Value6  | Value6  |
|      |     |      |    |       | Value7  | Value7  | Value7  |
| JMAP | 301 | 3315 | I6 | Cofow | Value8  | Value8  | Value8  |
| JMAP | 301 | 3916 | R6 |       | Value9  | Value9  | Value9  |
| JMAP | 305 | 3314 | I6 |       | Value10 | Value10 | Value10 |
| JMAP | 305 | 3315 | R6 |       | Value11 | Value11 | Value11 |
| JMAP | 305 | 3916 | R6 |       | Value12 | Value12 | Value12 |
|      |     |      |    |       | Value13 | Value13 | Value13 |
+------+-----+------+----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I have tried separating the columns into two different dataframes removing NA's and then combining them but then my data gets thrown off due to indexing.

```
df3=pd.concat([df2,df1], axis=1, ignore_index=False)
```

Any help or ideas would be awesome!

Many thanks,

Gist

Comment: if you separate them into 2 df, try `reset_index(drop=True)` before merging to fix the indexing issue

Answer (score 0):

> I then go to remove duplicates from the first 4 columns, then the last three columns, finally the middle column:

Assuming these are the steps you want to do, try [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html). Here's an example that will do this in your order in one command:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(
    subset=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']).drop_duplicates(
    subset=['col6', 'col7', 'col8']).drop_duplicates(
    subset=['col5'])
```

You can also play around with the `keep` parameter (e.g., `keep='first'` vs `keep='last'`) to change which rows to drop / keep.